# Printing running data

Tags: java, program-entry-point

How do you print data into your console from a running application as it runs?so that for instance, if your app is a game and you command one of the characters to do something, the command is printed out on the console?

Comment: run it in the console

Comment: Inside app System.out.print() ??

Comment: You seem to be describing logging.

Comment: I think you're gonna want a `LoggerFactoryFactory` or something.

Answer (score 1):

In java output through the console is achieved by using the standard output object "System.out". System.out gives access to 3 methods print, println, and printf. Each of these methods display and handle strings/data types a bit differently. In the method println(), it will display a new line of text every time its called by the program. You  can message through the console quickly by inserting text between  **" "**  inside the ().

**For Example:**

```
System.out.println("Message to console.");`
```

The output would result: Message to console.

The method print will display data where the last character of displayed data on the same line.

**For Example:**

```
System.out.print("Message to console.");
System.out.print("Message to console.");
```

The output would result: Message to console.Message to console.

-Since the method print displays data where the last character of data was on the same line resulting in the two messages displayed on the same line.

The method printf can display data in specific formats such as a float and double values to the 2nd,3rd,4th,etc decimal places. As well as aligning output into organized columns. For basic output to the console, printf isn't necessary to touch upon.

**To be a bit more specific to your question, You can try adding System.out.println() statements at the end of your methods. So if i had a method called moveCharacter that handled moving the character in a game, i would add a print statement at the last line of the method so every time that method executes, the message in the print statement is displayed in the console so you're aware that command was called during execution of the application.

**For Example :**

```
public void moveCharacter()
{ 
    System.out.println("Character has moved!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try System.out.println() in between the lines of your code or use logging feature of Java.

```
// move character...
System.out.println("Character moved");
```